# notepad++ auto-highlighting for xml

Tags: xml, notepad++

On Notepad++, unless I save a file with *.xml extension, it doesn't highlight (color) tags and values.

Is there anyway, I can get highlighting feature without saving a file?

Thanks

Comment: Set syntax in the language menu to XML. Btw, this is off topic I think.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! from menu bar select your language (alphabetically sorted)